# Getting warning of 'let' pattern has no effect; sub-pattern didn't bind any variables

Tags: swift, enums, pattern-matching

I'm doing the following, but I'm getting the following warning:

> 'let' pattern has no effect; sub-pattern didn't bind any variables

```
enum Seat {
    case middle
    case window
    case aisle(Int)
}

let m : Seat = .middle
let w : Seat = .window
let a : Seat = .aisle(5)

let seats = [m,w,a]

for seat in seats {
    if case let .middle = seat {
        print("middle")
    }
    if case let .window = seat {
        print("window")
    }
    if case let Seat.aisle(row) = seat {
        print("able to let row be the associatedvalue of seat; its value is: \(row)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's simple. In the three cases, only `aisle` has an associated value of type `Int`. Your `.middle` & `.window` cases don't have an associated value to extract ie there isn't a value to bind. Just knowing that that's the case is enough. To make the warning go away change:

```
if case let .middle = seat
```

to:

```
if case .middle = seat
```

same for your `.window` case

Answer (score 2):

You can use `switch`

```
 switch seat {
    case .middle:
        print("middle")
    case .window:
        print("window")
    case let .aisle(row):
        print("able to let row be the associatedvalue of seat; its value is: \(row)")
}
```

Comment: The last case can also be written as `case .aisle(let row):` which makes the 3 cases more uniform and emphasizes that `row` is the variable being bound. Both ways are valid and it’s merely a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other 2 correct answers, if you make `Seat` `Equatable`, you can compare with `==` for the cases that don't have an associated value:

```
enum Seat: Equatable {
    case middle
    case window
    case aisle(Int)
}

let m : Seat = .middle
let w : Seat = .window
let a : Seat = .aisle(5)

let seats = [m,w,a]

for seat in seats {
    if seat == .middle {
        print("middle")
    }
    else if seat == .window {
        print("window")
    }
    else if case .aisle(let row) = seat {
        print("able to let row be the associatedvalue of seat; its value is: \(row)")
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have also rewritten the last case as `if case .aisle(let row) = seat` which I think makes the *let binding* clearer when there is only a single variable to bind.

Comment: Interesting thing about `Equatable`. Didn't think of that. I actually like it the other way. I can then read it as such: _if I can let row be the associated value of the aisle case_. Yours is hard to read for me. I could read it as: _If aisle case can let row be its associated value_ but that sounds wordy to me. Does that make sense?

Comment: The thing about opinion is that both are valid. The variable being bound is the associated value, so I think having the `let` next to the `row` emphasizes that. If used with a `switch` all 3 cases would start with `.` giving them a more uniform look.